# 0x V4 Websocket connection

Tags: websocket

Is the 0x V4 Websocket server down? It was working for me a few days ago, but now I am getting the error "server rejected WebSocket connection: HTTP 400". Has anything changed?

Comment: Http error 400 means that your request isn't valid. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400. Did you change anything about that request from the last time it worked?

Comment: Nothing has changed on my end. Exactly the same code that was working no longer works. I get the error when trying to establish the connection. The only argument is the address "wss://api.0x.org/v4".  I wonder if this has changed.